# Azure: no module named pip

Tags: python, azure, pip, importerror

I tried to push my code to Azure Web App, but got this error:

```
remote: Found compatible virtual environment.
remote: Pip install requirements.
remote: Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:   File "D:\python34\lib\runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
remote:     "__main__", mod_spec)
remote:   File "D:\python34\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
remote: An error has occurred during web site deployment.
remote:     exec(code, run_globals)
remote:   File "D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
remote: ImportError: No module named 'pip'
```

The funny thing is that it worked five or six hours ago.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found an answer by myself.

Just come to:

```
D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\Scripts
```

and used

```
easy_install.exe -U pip
```

So, that was simple.